# Problem registering gmail in iPad

Tags: ipad, email, gmail, accounts

I recently changed the password for my gmail account. I was able to register the account on my iPhone but when I do the same on my iPad it tells me that the user id and password are incorrect. I changed the password again but the problem persisted. When I access gmail via Safari or Chrome there is no problem.

Comment: Have you tried to delete (and so remove) the Gmail account from the device and restart the procedure to add it as new account? This reset should help you to solve the problem.

Answer (score -3):

Reset the settings on your iPad and then set up everything from scratch. Use the instructions from Apple Support article below. There's no need to change a password to use gmail account on iPad.

[Add an email account to your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201320)